# vue handling 2 file inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

I created 2 input type files like this:

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="file"
    class="inputfile"
    accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
    @change="FileChange1"
    v-if="!tombolHidden"
    ref="myFiles1"
  />
```

with `onchange` listener

```
FileChange1(e) {
  console.log(e);

  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  // e.target.value = '';
  if (!files.length) return;
  this.createImage(files[0]);
  this.tombolHidden = true;
  this.placeHolder1 = true;
  this.hiddenEl = false;
},
createImage(file) {
  console.log(file);

  var image = new Image();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var vm = this;

  reader.onload = e => {
    vm.gambar1 = e.target.result;
    console.log(vm.gambar1);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

and

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="file"
    class="inputfile"
    accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
    ref="myFiles2"
    @change="FileChange2"
    v-if="!tombolHidden2"
  />
```

with onchange listener

```
FileChange2(e) {
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!files.length) return;
  this.createImage2(files[0]);
  this.tombolHidden2 = true;
  this.placeHolder2 = true;
  this.hiddenEl2 = false;
},
createImage2(file) {
  console.log(file);

  var image = new Image();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var vm = this;

  reader.onload = e => {
    vm.gambar2 = e.target.result;
    console.log(vm.gambar2);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

**My question**: why when I click the upload button in file 2 with `onchange` method `FileChange2()` [image: like this image] this.. execute methods `FileChange1()` what could be wrong?

Comment: while you don't seem to reference the `id` directly, you have the same `id` for both inputs. change them perhaps to `file1` and `file2`  There might be some reference to `id` under the hood.

Comment: Please show us all lines of this code (html, js) for use that in https://codepen.io/. Or give us ling from https://codepen.io/ for testing your code!